# Regex extract from tag a href only if rel=

Tags: regex, preg-match, extract

Please help with regex to extract from tag a href only if rel="external nofollow"

```
<a href="text.html" rel="external nofollow">text1:text2:text3/</a>
```

only need as result get

```
text1:text2:text3
```

then trying

```
$regexp = '<a (?![^>]*?rel="external nofollow")[^>]*?href="(.*?)"';
```

I get error

```
Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier ']' in /
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have to get proper delimiters around your regex, a suitable one here is `~`:

```
$regexp = '~<a (?![^>]*?rel="external nofollow")[^>]*?href="(.*?)"~';
```

Second, this regex will be matching anything between the anchor tag and capture the link in `href` and only if there's no `rel="external nofollow"` in the anchor tag, which I thought was the opposite of what you're trying to do. Negative lookaheads *prevent* matches. You might want to change that regex completely to something like:

```
$regexp = '~<a[^>]*?rel="external nofollow"[^>]*>(.*?)</a>~';
```

Instead.

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/wK0dV9)

Comment: @ValdemarZ Huh, you're using that regex against a whole webpage? Well, you'll be better off with a proper HTML parser. Regex works fine as long as there's not too much or you have a good idea of the complexity of the file you're parsing.

Answer (score 3):

I strongly advise against use of regex for this type of task of parsing HTML. HTML can vary a lot and you can get unexpected results.

Consider using [`DOM parser in PHP`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) like this code:

```
$html = '<a href="found.html" rel="external nofollow">text1:text2:text3/</a>
         <a href="notfound.html" rel="external">text11/</a>';
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html); // loads your html
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$nodelist = $xpath->query("//a[contains(@rel, 'external nofollow')]");
for($i=0; $i < $nodelist->length; $i++) {
   $node = $nodelist->item($i);
   echo $node->getAttribute('href') . "\n";
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
found.html
```

Answer (score 3):

I suggest that you use [DOM](http://de.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) to parse and get your desired results. Below is an example for this.

```
<?php
$str = <<<STR
<a href="text.html" rel="external nofollow">foo bar</a>
<a href="text.html" rel="nofollow">text1:text2:text3/</a>
<a href="text.html" rel="nofollow">text1:text2:text3/</a>
<a href="example.html" rel="external nofollow">bar baz</a>
STR;

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($str);

foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $node) {
   if ($node->getAttribute('rel') == 'external nofollow') {
     echo $node->getAttribute('href') . ', ' . $node->nodeValue . "\n"; 
   }
}
?>
```

Output from example:

```
text.html, foo bar
example.html, bar baz
```

Comment: Good point about using DOM but it just came 10 min behind my answer :P

Comment: Yea I didn't refresh the page to see your already posted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
preg_match('/<a.*rel="external nofollow"[^>]*>([^<]*)</a>/i',
           $string_to_search_through, $res);
echo $res[1];
```

`$res[1]` will give you the desired text.

Comment: Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier 'a' in /